# Hover behaviour issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have the follow jQuery event binding. Refer to the image below to see the DOM. The hover callbacks behave correctly when hovering over `.gift-price`, `.gift-vendor`, and `.gift-name`. However, when hovering over the image (`.gift-photo`), the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` callbacks are called for every movement of the mouse. Why is this happening?

```
$('div.gift-gallery-item').hover(
    function(e) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var itemWidth = $(this).width();
        var itemHeight = $(this).height();
    
        var hoverItem = $('div#gift-gallery-item-hover');
        hoverItem.height(140).width(itemWidth * 2);
        hoverItem.css('left', offset.left).css('top', offset.top);
        hoverItem.show();
                                            
        console.log('in: ' + offset.left +', '+ offset.top);
        console.log(this);
    },
    function(e) {
        $('div#gift-gallery-item-hover').hide();
        console.log('out!');
    } 
)
```

#### DOM Reference Image

The yellow boxes are `.gift-gallery-item` divs:

[image]

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the hovering div (absolutely positioned) interfering with the mouse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678260/mouseover-triggered-on-absolute-positioned-div

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Basically hover was behaving correctly, but when the absolutely positioned hover info div was under the mouse, the mouseleave event was being trigged on the gift-gallery-item. Simple solution was to split up the hover into its mouseenter and mouseleave events, and bind mouseleave only once using `one()` instead of `bind()`. Then in the hover info div's mouseleave event, i rebind the mouseleave on the gift-gallery-item.

```
$('div.gift-gallery-item').bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var itemWidth = $(this).width();
    var itemHeight = $(this).height();

    var hoverItem = $('div#gift-gallery-item-hover');
    hoverItem.height(140).width(itemWidth * 2);
    hoverItem.css('left', offset.left).css('top', offset.top);
    hoverItem.show();

    console.log('in: ' + offset.left +', '+ offset.top);
    console.log(this);
});

$('div.gift-gallery-item').one('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEvent);

var mouseLeaveEvent = function() {
    $('div#gift-gallery-item-hover').hide();
    console.log('out!');
};

$('div#gift-gallery-item-hover').hover(
    function(e) {

    },
    function(e) {
        $('div.gift-gallery-item').one('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEvent);
    }
);
```